# Setting up test audience for a/b testing

Tags: ab-test

I am trying to design a test for our marketing team. Right now they run a lot of experiments focussed on gamification and points.
Let's assume a hypothetical situation for spotify
**Experiment Set Up**
Hypothesis : UserS who listens to atleast 6 songs are more likely to continue to engage in the spotify platform. So they want to get the users who listen to 1 song from 6 songs because thats where they think the biggest drop off.

Control Group : Users who does not receive any communication
Experiment Group A: Users who receive a nudge
Experiment Group B : Users who receive a nudge and extra badge

The test audience criteria they have set up is users who have listened to only one song in the past two weeks. I feel like this is too narrow to capture any effect size.
What would be the best way to design test audience for this setup.
Some alternatives I have considered are
a) Users who are active in the past 30 days and listed to atleast 1 song. The issue is that there might be a certain set of users who are hyper active
b) Users who are 180 d active . The issue is that there might be users who have stopped engaging with the platform